# Pointer changes value after printf

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, printf, clang

So today I was trying to implement simple stack in C, but I have encountered following issue that I can't resolve or explain why is happening.

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct stack_element stack_element;
typedef struct stack stack;

struct stack_element
{
    void* data;
    stack_element* next;
};

struct stack
{
    stack_element* top;
    int size;
    int max_size;
};

void push(stack* this, stack_element to_add)
{
    if(this->top == NULL)
    {
        this->top = &to_add;
        this->top->next = this->top;
        printf("%p\n", this->top);
        printf("%p\n", this->top->next);
        printf("First\n");
        return;
    }
}

void debug(stack* this)
{
    if(this->top == NULL) return;
    printf("Sample 1 %p\n", this->top);
    printf("Sample 2 %p\n\n", this->top->next);
}

int main()
{
    stack_element* tmp = malloc(sizeof(stack_element));
    stack* st = malloc(sizeof(stack)); 
    tmp->data = 1;
    push(st, *tmp);
    printf("Sample 1 %p\n", st->top);
    printf("Sample 2 %p\n\n", st->top->next);
    debug(st);
    printf("Sample 1 %p\n", st->top);
    printf("Sample 2 %p\n\n", st->top->next);
    printf("END\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Code above gives some strange results, and also different ones if I change compiler.

First compiler I've tried is gcc and it gives following output:

```
0x7ffd6d96d3b0
0x7ffd6d96d3b0
First
Sample 1 0x7ffd6d96d3b0
Sample 2 0x7ffd6d96d3b0

Sample 1 0x7ffd6d96d3b0
Sample 2 0x400670

Sample 1 0x7ffd6d96d3b0
Sample 2 0x40068d

END
```

Second result is from clang:

```
0x7ffd6d05fb30
0x7ffd6d05fb30
First
Sample 1 0x7ffd6d05fb30
Sample 2 0x7ffd6d05fb30

Sample 1 0x7ffd6d05fb30
Sample 2 0x2042030

Sample 1 0x7ffd6d05fb30
Sample 2 0x2042030

END
```

**My first question is why is Sample 2 even changing when I printf it from void debug?** Also I have tried to comment out debug function call and results are also strange. In gcc samples are as expected all are matching, but in clang there is difference in sample 2 for no obvious reason.

**My second question is why is there even difference between compilers while compiling this code?**

Hope I have posted enough information about the issue I am having, if not write me in comment to post more information.

Comment: Your `push` function changes `this->top` to point to a value on the stack. This value goes out of scope after the function ends (ending its lifetime) creating a dangling pointer, so dereferencing it via `this->top->next` invokes *undefined behavior*

Comment: So is it then good idea to malloc new variable and attach that to this->top?

Comment: I added some explanations via an answer - I hope that makes it clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `push` function takes the second parameter by value, so it creates a local copy of the `struct stack_element`. That means the line `this->top = &to_add;` redirects the pointer `top` to point at a local variable (with automatic storage duration). After the function `push` ends that variable's lifetime ends, changing `top` into a dangling pointer. Thus the dereferencing `this->top->next` (and `st->top->next`) invoke *undefined behavior*.

What you most likely intended to do was take the second parameter for `push` as a pointer: `void push(stack* this, stack_element* to_add)` and change the line:

```
this->top = &to_add;
```

to

```
this->top = to_add;
```

NOTE: Your suggestion of using `malloc` inside `push` is another possibility, however that might create unclear code, as it would require the caller to know that `top` needs to be `free`d in order to avoid memory leaks. Alternatively you could also provide a "destructor" function which would take care of all memory management, hiding it from the caller.

Comment: Thanks for fantastic answer UnholySheep. Solution that you have proposed works like a charm. And most importantly I have learned something. Thanks again :D