# Function seems to change where pointer is pointing to

Tags: c

I have written following C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *getPointer(int var);
void anotherFunction();

int main ( int argc , char * argv [])
{
  int *intPtr = getPointer(3); 
  printf("%d\n",*intPtr);
  anotherFunction();
  printf ("%d\n",*intPtr);
  getPointer(5);
  printf("%d\n", *intPtr);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS ;
}

// Which problem occurs here?
int *getPointer(int var) {
  int *ptr=&var;
  return ptr;
}
void anotherFunction(){
  // do nothing
  int a [ 5 ] = { 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 };
}
```

The Output is:

```
3
7
5
```

I do not understand why the value of intPtr changes in the second printf() call. I would appreciate your help!
Thank you

Comment: What output do you exepct? Please [edit] the question.

Comment: you can take look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42735993/pointer-changes-value-after-printf

Answer (score 1):

This function is totally pointless and wrong:

```
int *getPointer(int var) {
  int *ptr = &var;
  return ptr;
}
```

`ptr` points to the local variable `var` (yes function parameters are more or less the same as local variables). But as soon as the function returns, that variable doesn't exist anymore. So the pointer returned by `getPointer` points basically to junk.

Answer (score 0):

The pointer you are getting is a pointer to `var` local variable. And that variable is stored in the **STACK** (not in heap).

So, a couple of things:

1. Relying on pointers to **STACK** variables after the function call ended is just **WRONG**. Don't do that. Never.
2. The second `printf` is printing something in the stack that was overwritten when you called `anotherFunction`. This worked in this case, but this behavior is UNDEFINED (it could also lead to a SEGMENTATION FAULT).